# Base query does not provide ASC order over dedicated TIMESTAMP column

Tags: questdb

I get the following error when trying a query using `SAMPLE BY`

> base query does not provide ASC order over dedicated TIMESTAMP column

Here is the query I am attempting to execute

```
select TS,COUNT(*) total from tOrders sample by 1M
```

The `TS` column is the table's *timestamp*. I did not find any documentation related to this error. I searched the documentation and the QuestDB repository issues list looking for information but came up empty.

Answer (score 2):

The error means that TS it not the table's [dedicated timestamp](https://questdb.io/docs/concept/designated-timestamp/).
If you create table as:

```sql
create table tOrders ( ts timestamp, value long ) timestamp(ts);
```

then query should run fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The colum is already timestamp.

CREATE TABLE 'tOrders' (
  ID INT,
  TS TIMESTAMP,
  SampleID STRING,
  RegisterDate STRING,
  RegisterHour STRING,
  RegisterYear INT,
  rPatients INT,
  Doctor STRING,
  Service STRING,
  Destination STRING,
  Origin STRING,
  Location INT,
  Sex STRING,
  DateOfBirth STRING
);

Comment: I think I did the table create wrong... how can I alter table and add the timestamp column?

Comment: Adding designated timestamp column is not possible but you can create new table with the designated timestamp  and then copy data to it, e.g. 


CREATE TABLE new_tOrders ( ... ) TIMESTAMP(TS) PARTITION BY MONTH; 
INSERT INTO new_tOrders select * from tOrders;
DROP TABLE tOrders;
RENAME TABLE new_tOrders to tOrders;